# Sub-setting data using %in%

Tags: r, subset

I have used the subset function many times and also %in% separately. I have seen many questions on here pertaining to using them together and thought my code would work, however the code provided is not performing the sub-setting properly.

Here is an example of what I have tried:

```
remove_sells <- subset(portfolio, !(portfolio$Ticker %in% sells$Ticker))
```

Instead of returning the values which are unique to sells it is returning the original portfolio.

Comment: You should provide some sample data to test, along with the expected outcome and what you are currently getting.

Comment: It should work. Maybe it fails somehow thanks to R's "factor" data type. Hard to know without a concrete example.

Comment: Why not just use `portfolio[!(portfolio$Ticker %in% sells$Ticker), ]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested your code and it seems to work nicely.

```
portfolio <- data.frame(c("GOOG","AAPL","FB"))
colnames(portfolio) <- "Ticker"
sells <- data.frame(c("AAPL"))
colnames(sells) <- "Ticker"

portfolio <- cbind(portfolio, c(2000,3000,4000))
colnames(portfolio)[2] <- "VolTraded"

remove_sells <- subset(portfolio, !(portfolio$Ticker %in% sells$Ticker))
```

Result:

```
> remove_sells
  Ticker VolTraded
1   GOOG      2000
3     FB      4000
```

Comment: I also tested just using some vectors and found his code worked as well.